# Why would I make() or new()?

Tags: go

The introduction documents dedicate many paragraphs to explaining the difference between `new()` and `make()`, but in practice, you can create objects within local scope and return them.

Why would you use the pair of allocators?

Answer (score 299, accepted):

Go has multiple ways of memory allocation and value initialization:

`&T{...}`, `&someLocalVar`, `new`, `make`

Allocation can also happen when creating composite literals.

---

`new` can be used to allocate values such as integers, `&int` is illegal:

```
new(Point)
&Point{}      // OK
&Point{2, 3}  // Combines allocation and initialization

new(int)
&int          // Illegal

// Works, but it is less convenient to write than new(int)
var i int
&i
```

The difference between `new` and `make` can be seen by looking at the following example:

```
p := new(chan int)   // p has type: *chan int
c := make(chan int)  // c has type: chan int
```

Suppose Go does not have `new` and `make`, but it has the built-in function `NEW`. Then the example code would look like this:

```
p := NEW(*chan int)  // * is mandatory
c := NEW(chan int)
```

The `*` *would be mandatory*, so:

```
new(int)        -->  NEW(*int)
new(Point)      -->  NEW(*Point)
new(chan int)   -->  NEW(*chan int)
make([]int, 10) -->  NEW([]int, 10)

make(Point)  // Illegal
make(int)    // Illegal
```

Yes, merging `new` and `make` into a single built-in function is possible. However, it is probable that a single built-in function would lead to more confusion among new Go programmers than having two built-in functions.

Considering all of the above points, it appears more appropriate for `new` and `make` to remain separate.

Comment: @TorstenBronger I find new to be easier to read and shows that that is the instance where the `int` is created.

Comment: Did you mean to write `make(Point)` and `make(int)` in those last 2 lines?

Comment: yes they did, so I fixed it.

Comment: I don't think this answer addressed the question. A better one would be by @cod3rboy below.

Answer (score 231):

Things you can do with `make` that you can't do any other way:

- Create a channel
- Create a map with space preallocated
- Create a slice with space preallocated or with len != cap

It's a little harder to justify `new`. The main thing it makes easier is creating pointers to non-composite types.
The two functions below are equivalent. One's just a little more concise:

```
func newInt1() *int { return new(int) }

func newInt2() *int {
    var i int
    return &i
}
```

Comment: It is true that 'new' cannot be used to create channels. However, in my opinion, the point is: what would happen if 'new' and 'make' are joined into a single built-in function? Certainly, such a replacement would be possible. Since it is possible, the question is: what are the objective reasons for having 2 built-in functions rather than just 1 generalized built-in function. - Your answer correctly says that 'new' cannot be used to create channels/maps/slices, but it does not provide justifications as to **why** Go has 'new' and 'make', instead of having 1 generalized alloc+init function.

Comment: They could be combined and it was even proposed by Rob Pike at one point: https://groups.google.com/d/topic/golang-nuts/kWXYU95XN04/discussion. Ultimately it didn't go through for reasons similar to the ones given in your answer.

Comment: Effective go makes the point that new returns a zeroed value, whereas map allocates non-zeroed types map, slice or channel.  See http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#allocation_new

Comment: What about `m := map[string]int{}` instead of `m := make(map[string]int)`? no need to preallocate size as well.

Comment: This seems equivalent to the general confusion between interfaces and pointers that coders from dynamic scripting languages have when coming to Go. I see questions regularly "why does HttpHandler take a ResponseWriter by value but it takes a pointer to a Request?". It takes time for newcomers to grok pointers, even in the simplified form available in Go.

Answer (score 47):

`make` function allocates and initializes an object of type slice, map, or chan only. Like `new`, the first argument is a type. But, it can also take a second argument, the size. Unlike new, make’s return type is the same as the type of its argument, not a pointer to it. And the allocated value is initialized (not set to zero value like in new). **The reason is that slice, map and chan are data structures. They need to be initialized, otherwise they won't be usable.** This is the reason new() and make() need to be different.

The following examples from Effective Go make it very clear:

```
p *[]int = new([]int) // *p = nil, which makes p useless
v []int = make([]int, 100) // creates v structure that has pointer to an array, length field, and capacity field. So, v is immediately usable
```

Comment: In `new([]int)`, it just allocates memory for []int, but not initializing so it just returns `nil`; not the pointer to the memory because it is unusable. `make([]int)` allocates and initialize so it's usable, then return its address.

Comment: *"*p = nil, which makes p useless"* - I don't think that's correct. `p` isn't useless. A `nil` slice behaves mostly like an empty slice. For example, you can append to it: `*p = append(*p, 1)`

Answer (score 37):

- `new(T)` - Allocates memory, and sets it to the **zero value** for type **T**..
  ..that is `0` for *int*, `""` for *string* and `nil` for referenced types (*slice*, *map*, *chan*)

  Note that referenced types are just pointers to some **underlying data structures**, which **won't be created** by `new(T)`
  Example: in case of *slice*, the underlying *array* won't be created, thus `new([]int)` 
  returns a pointer to nothing
- `make(T)` - Allocates memory for referenced data types (*slice*, *map*, *chan*), plus **initializes** their **underlying data structures**

  Example: in case of *slice*, the underlying *array* will be created with the specified length and capacity
  Bear in mind that, unlike C, an array is a primitive type in Go!

---

That being said:

`make(T)` behaves like composite-literal syntax

`new(T)` behaves like `var` (when the variable is not initialized)

```golang
func main() {
    fmt.Println("-- MAKE --")
    a := make([]int, 0)
    aPtr := &a
    fmt.Println("pointer == nil :", *aPtr == nil)
    fmt.Printf("pointer value: %p\n\n", *aPtr)

    fmt.Println("-- COMPOSITE LITERAL --")
    b := []int{}
    bPtr := &b
    fmt.Println("pointer == nil :", *bPtr == nil)
    fmt.Printf("pointer value: %p\n\n", *bPtr)

    fmt.Println("-- NEW --")
    cPtr := new([]int)
    fmt.Println("pointer == nil :", *cPtr == nil)
    fmt.Printf("pointer value: %p\n\n", *cPtr)

    fmt.Println("-- VAR (not initialized) --")
    var d []int
    dPtr := &d
    fmt.Println("pointer == nil :", *dPtr == nil)
    fmt.Printf("pointer value: %p\n", *dPtr)
}
```

Run the program

```sh
-- MAKE --
pointer == nil : false
pointer value: 0x118eff0  # address to underlying array

-- COMPOSITE LITERAL --
pointer == nil : false
pointer value: 0x118eff0  # address to underlying array

-- NEW --
pointer == nil : true
pointer value: 0x0

-- VAR (not initialized) --
pointer == nil : true
pointer value: 0x0
```

Further reading:
https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#allocation_new
https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#allocation_make

Answer (score 25):

There are already a lot of good answers but let me explain the need for new() and make() as separate allocators.

1. new(T) allocates *uninitialized zeroed* memory of the given type T and returns a *pointer* to that memory so that it is ready to use. Zeroed out just means that the allocated memory will have zero value of given type. Zero values of some go types are -

   - int - 0
   - bool - false
   - float - 0
   - string - ""
   - struct - Zero value of each member

Problem with new() arises when it needs to handle three other composite types - chan, slice and map.
These three types are special in essence that their underlying type is not just an another type but rather a *state* that needs to be initialized. For example , the underlying state of a slice consists of a pointer to the first element of internal array storage, a length that determines number of elements that can be accessed and a capacity that increases as the number of elements grow. new() certainly cannot handle allocation of such types due to their need for extra initialization step, that is where make() come into play.

2. make(T, args) is *specially* made for chan, slice and map types. It not only allocates the internal storage type of the chan, slice and map but also *initializes their underlying state* to make them ready to use. For example, for a slice it allocates the internal array storage, set the pointer to refer to first element in that array and set the length and capacity values.

Comment: This is a good argument. - New is very simple, it always does the same thing. Make is more like a function, which accepts dynamic parameters (length and capacity) and can possibly take a long time e.g. to initialize a big array. So for the programmer it is good to see the difference at first glance: make does some work, while new is quite simple.

Answer (score 21):

## Difference between new() and make():

- new(T) allocates zeroed storage for a new item of type T and returns its address, a value of type *T: it returns a pointer to a newly allocated zero value of type T, ready for use; it applies to value types like arrays and structs; it is
  equivalent to &T{ }
- make(T) returns an initialized value of type T; it applies only to the 3 built-in reference types: slices, maps and channels.

In other words, new allocates; make initializes;

[image]

```
var p *[]int = new([]int)
or
// *p == nil; with len and cap 0
p := new([]int)
```

which is only rarely useful.

[image]

```
p := make([]int, 0)
```

our slice is initialized, but here points to an empty array.

Both these statements aren't very useful, the following is:

```
var v []int = make([]int, 10, 50)
// Or
v := make([]int, 10, 50)
```

This allocates an array of 50 ints and then creates a slice v with length 10 and capacity 50 pointing to the first 10 elements of the array.

## Find out some rules for make() and new():

- For slices, maps and channels: use make
- For arrays, structs and all value types: use new

---

```
package main
type Foo map[string]string
type Bar struct {
         s string
         i int
}
func main() {
         // OK:
         y := new(Bar)
         (*y).s = "hello"
         (*y).i = 1

         // NOT OK:
         z := make(Bar) // compile error: cannot make type Bar
         z.s = "hello"
         z.i = 1

         // OK:
         x := make(Foo)
         x["x"] = "goodbye"
         x["y"] = "world"

         // NOT OK:
         u := new(Foo)
         (*u)["x"] = "goodbye" // !!panic!!: runtime error: 
                   // assignment to entry in nil map
         (*u)["y"] = "world"
}
```

Channel:

```
func main() {
    // OK:
    ch := make(chan string)
    go sendData(ch)
    go getData(ch)
    time.Sleep(1e9)

    // NOT OK:
    ch := new(chan string)
    go sendData(ch) // cannot use ch (variable of type *chan string) 
                   // as chan string value in argument to sendData
    go getData(ch)
    time.Sleep(1e9)
}

func sendData(ch chan string) {
    ch <- "Washington"
    ch <- "Tripoli"
    ch <- "London"
    ch <- "Beijing"
    ch <- "Tokio"
}

func getData(ch chan string) {
    var input string
    for {
        input = <-ch
        fmt.Printf("%s ", input)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 20):

`new(T)`: it returns a **pointer to type `T`** a value of type `*T`, it allocates and zeroes the memory. **`new(T)` is equivalent to `&T{}`**.

`make(T)`: it returns an **initialized value of type `T`**, It allocates and initializes the memory. Its used for slices, map and channels.

Answer (score 13):

You need `make()` to create channels and maps (and slices, but those can be created from arrays too). There's no alternative way to make those, so you can't remove `make()` from your lexicon.

As for `new()`, I don't know of any reason offhand why you *need* it when you can use struct syntax. It does have a unique semantic meaning though, which is "create and return a struct with all fields initialized to their zero value", which can be useful.

Comment: So new should be avoided and just prefer the use of Struct syntax

Answer (score 10):

The benefits of "make" are heavily covered in other answers, but "New" has an added bonus over make not mentioned above: generics (as of 1.18).

Let's say you have a set of flat (all fields are primitives) structs, like the following:

```
type SomeStruct struct {
    V1 string `json:"v1"`
    V2 string `json:"v2"`
}
```

and you want to create a mapping function that turns a map[string]string into any struct. Then you could write:

```
func GetStructFromMap[T any](values map[string]string) (T, error) {
    myStr := T{}
    bytes, err := json.Marshal(values)
    if err != nil {
        return *myStr, err
    }

    if err := json.Unmarshal(bytes, str); err != nil {
        return *myStr, err
    }

    return *myStr, nil
}
```

but, this code will throw an error, with regards to the line `myStr := T{}`, about an invalid composite value. Replacing it with `myStr := make(T)` will through another error about no underlying type. So, you'll to replace the line with `myStr := new(T)` which will create a reference to a zeroed value instance of the struct.

As can be seen, when dealing with generics, `new` can be used to instantiate a type that is unknown at compile time.

As a side, you could have also used named return types in this specific example, but the more general usage still stands.

Answer (score 8):

Apart from everything explained in [Effective Go](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#allocation_new), The main difference between `new(T)` and `&T{}` is that the latter explicitly performs a heap allocation. However it should be noted that this is implementation dependent and thus may be subject to change.

Comparing `make` to `new` makes little sense as the two perform entirely different functions. But this is explained in detail in the linked article.

Comment: The claim that `&T{}` explicitly performs a heap allocation is AFAIK not based on anything in the specs. Actually I believe escape analysis are already keeping such *T on stack whenever possible in the exactly same way as with `new(T)`.

Answer (score -3):

I think `new` just allocates memory while `make` also allocates memory but additionally executes the internal constructor for internal data structures.

Against this background it is inconsistent that most constructors are prefixed with `New`. It would be more consistent to prefix them with `Make`.