# Is there a difference between new() and "regular" allocation?

Tags: go

In Go, is there a notable difference between the following two segments of code:

```
v := &Vector{}
```

as opposed to

```
v := new(Vector)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Go: why would I make() or new()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9320862/go-why-would-i-make-or-new)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

No. What they return is the same,

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "reflect"

type Vector struct {
    x   int
    y   int
}

func main() {
    v := &Vector{}
    x := new(Vector)
    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(v))
    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(x))
}
```

Result:

```
*main.Vector
*main.Vector
```

There is some contention on the mailing list that having both is confusing:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/golang-nuts/GDXFDJgKKSs

One thing to note:

> new() is the only way to get a pointer to an
>   unnamed integer or other basic type.  You can write "p := new(int)" but
>   you can't write "p := &int{0}".  Other than that, it's a matter of
>   preference.

Source : https://groups.google.com/d/msg/golang-nuts/793ZF_yeqbk/-zyUAPT-e4IJ

Comment: I guess they could support `p := &0` if they wanted to keep the keyword count down.

Answer (score 25):

Yes, there is a fundamental difference between the two code fragments.

```
v := &Vector{}
```

Works **only** for `Vector` being a struct type, map type, array type or a slice type

```
v := new(Vector)
```

Works for `Vector` of **any** type.

Example: http://play.golang.org/p/nAHjL1ZEuu

Comment: Saying `new(Map)` isn't a good idea though: http://play.golang.org/p/u89EYchY5n - maps, slices and channels must be made with `make()`, and since they are reference types anyway making them with `new()` is pointless.

Comment: That's not a problem of `new`. Actually there's nothing wrong with `new(anyType)`: http://play.golang.org/p/e3hmtK_IV8

Comment: You are correct, but it is still pointless as a `map` is a pointer already so `make()` is the correct thing to use, not `new()`.

Comment: That's not true. The previous example showed that using a map doesn't require "making" it (e.g. `m := map[t]u{}`, although it is `make`ed by compiler magic). Secondly, map is not a pointer type and even though we know that actually it is implemented as a pointer to some run time structures, still pointers to pointers do have completely legitimate uses. There  is nothing wrong in `new(anyType)` per se. The design/intent might be wrong, but that's a different topic.

Answer (score -5):

Here is a difference: for a `Person` struct, the JSON string marshalled from `&[]*Person{}` is `[]` and from `new([]*Person)` is `null` using `json.Marshal`.

Check out the sample here: https://play.golang.org/p/xKkFLoMXX1s

- https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#allocation_new
- https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#composite_literals