# multiple sync.WaitGroup usage

Tags: pointers, go, concurrency

I have seen a few different examples of `sync.WaitGroup`

Example 1

```
var wg sync.WaitGroup

wg.Add(1)
go doStuff(&wg)
wg.Wait()
```

Example 2

```
wg := new(sync.WaitGroup)

wg.Add(1)
go doStuff(wg)
wg.Wait()
```

the difference is really in the way `sync.WaitGroup` is initialized
`var` vs `new`

if using the `var` option it has to be passed as a pointer `&wg` to the goroutine but if I use the `new` option I can send it as `wg`

What is the difference between the two examples? Which of these 2 above is correct? Is one preferred over the other in certain situations?

I am writing a program which creates multiple `sync.WaitGroup`s so does it matter if `new` or `var` is used?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a difference between new() and "regular" allocation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13244947/is-there-a-difference-between-new-and-regular-allocation)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both of your examples work properly. Also note that instead of `new()`, you could also use a [composite literal](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals) and take its address like this:

```
var wg = &sync.WaitGroup{}
```

Methods of [`sync.WaitGroup`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup) have pointer receiver, so whenever you call its methods, the address of the `WaitGroup` struct value is needed. This is not a problem, as when `wg` is a non-pointer, the `wg.Add(1)` and `wg.Done()` calls are shorthand for `(&wg).Add(1)` and `(&wg).Done()`, so the compiler automatically "rewrites" those calls to take the address of `wg` first, and use that address as the receiver of the methods.

However, I still think that if a value is only useful as a pointer (`sync.WaitGroup` is a shining example), you should declare it and work with it as a pointer in the first place, so that leaves less room for errors.

For example, if you use a non-pointer and you declare the function to expect a non-pointer, and you pass it as a non-pointer, you will get no compile-time error, yet it will misbehave (`sync.WaitGroup` should not be copied).

Although today's linter would give you a warning message, still, I believe it's best to work with pointers all the time.

Another reason to work with pointers: if a function would return a `sync.WaitGroup`, or if you have a map that stores `sync.WaitGroup` as values, you would not be able to call methods on the result, because return values of functions and map index operations are not addressable. If the function would return a pointer value, or if you would store pointers in the map in the first place, you could still call the methods without having to store them in a local variable. For details, see [How can I store reference to the result of an operation in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34197248/how-can-i-store-reference-to-the-result-of-an-operation-in-go/34197367#34197367)

For example:

```
func getWg() sync.WaitGroup { return sync.WaitGroup{} }

getWg().Wait() // Compile-time error!

m := map[int]sync.WaitGroup{
    1: sync.WaitGroup{},
}

m[1].Wait() // Again: compile-time error
```

But these work:

```
func getWg() *sync.WaitGroup { return &sync.WaitGroup{} }

getWg().Wait() // Works, you can call methods on the return value

m := map[int]*sync.WaitGroup{
    1: &sync.WaitGroup{},
}

m[1].Wait() // Also works
```

Read more about this here: [Why should constructor of Go return address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31932822/why-should-constructor-of-go-return-address/31934189#31934189)

Comment: Thanks, it helps to understand that both are correct. Since the `new` / composite literal technique creates a pointer. are you suggesting to use Example 2 style since `var` is a non-pointer?

Comment: @rrag Yes, I'm suggesting to use example 2, and it's more common to use `&sync.WaitGroup{}` than `new(sync.WaitGroup)`, although they do the same.