# What does the "make" function do to a map in this context

Tags: struct, go

I am new to Go and was looking for a tutorial on forms a few days ago, and now that I've familiarized myself a bit more I was attempting to create my own error handler that I could use with all of my structs, sort of like an abstract class, but the example I got from the tutorial I saw has me a bit stumped.

Here is a small example I played with to test what the `make` function was doing. I kind of figured it out by tinkering, but I don't understand what it's *actually* doing, and why it is necessary.

```
type ErrorHandler struct {
    Errors map[string]string
}

type Form struct {
    ErrorHandler
}

func main() {
    form := &Form{}

    if true {
        fmt.Printf("%p\n", &form.Errors)
    } else {
        form.Errors = make(map[string]string)
        fmt.Printf("%p\n", &form.Errors)
    }
}
```

In the example above, I try changing the if statement from true to false to see if the memory address changes based on whether the `make` function is used or not and it stays the same both cases. I read the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9320862/go-why-would-i-make-or-new) and he said one of its uses is to "create a map with space preallocated" -- which honestly doesn't mean much to me since I'm new to pointers and all that, but the "create a map" part had me thinking it's like reinitializing that Errors map in the ErrorHandler struct, which would assign it to a new memory address, yes? But no, they stay the same.

So I tried creating a value in the map, once *without* the make function and once *with* the make function. The `if` condition gives me an error saying `assignment to entry in nil map` and `goroutine [running]`, and the `else` statement prints "haha", which is what I set it to:

```
type ErrorHandler struct {
    Errors map[string]string
}

type Form struct {
    ErrorHandler
}

func main() {
    form := &Form{}

    if true {
        form.Errors["blah"] = "haha"
        fmt.Printf(form.Errors["blah"])
    } else {
        form.Errors = make(map[string]string)
        form.Errors["blah"] = "haha"
        fmt.Printf(form.Errors["blah"])
    }
}
```

So I sort of see what the make function is doing, but not exactly. As far as I can tell if I am going to "push" items into that map I need to use the `make` function, but I don't see why it's necessary. Why is the `map[string]string` set to nil in my struct because when I print it out I see "map[]" and not "nil"... that's confusing.

Can someone explain please? And how is this `goroutine` used here? Maybe that's the answer I'm looking for.. never used that before.

Also, since I have to use `make`, is there a way to kind of make it happen automatically instead of having to put it at the top of each method?

For example in my ErrorHandler struct I have a method that looks like this:

```
func (this *ErrorHandler) HandleErr(err string) {
    this.Errors = make(map[string]string)
    this.Errors["Error"] = err
}
```

and in my Form struct I also have another method that is validating the form, but also uses the `this.Errors = make(map[string]string) at the top of the method... feels non-DRY to me.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Think of a map as a struct containing a pointer to the underling map structure and a size (there may be other stuff, not sure).

For example, think of it like:

```
struct Map {
  data *Entries
  size int
}
```

make, allocates the initial value of Entries according to the size passed to make (if any)

When you say:

```
form.Errors = make(map[string]string)
```

it's like saying:

```
form.Errors = struct { data : malloc(sizeof(Entries)*capacity), size : 0 }
```

which copies the "data" and "size" variables in to your form.Errors

The actual field "form.Errors" is still the same place in memory, the internal values of form.Errors have changed to match what make returned.

So, the address doesn't change when you look at &form.Errors

As for the nil error when pushing to a map you didn't `make`...

An un-maid map has no "data" segment yet, so you get a nil pointer error.

Not unlike doing:

```
var i *int
*i = 5
```

Also results in a nil error

Hopefully that all made sense and helps shed a bit of light on the confusion.

Comment: Hmm still trying to grok that.. I think my lack of knowledge of pointers/memory is failing me here. This is my first "lower level" language. If make "allocates memory and initializes the map", as quoted in the other answer, then what is naming it in the struct doing? like what does `type ErrorHandler struct { Errors map[string]string }` do if it isn't either allocating memory or initializing 'Errors'? Is it just saying "here you are, you can be called, but can't be used because you don't quite exist yet until being created with memory allocation and initialization"?

Comment: maps are basically a reference type, meaning a type that refers to some other piece of memory.  That other piece of memory being nil by default.  If you are familiar with Java, it's like class Foo { String someString }.  When you do new Foo(), Your Foo instance has reference to a null String.  Until you assign it a value, any operation on that string is  NullPointerException.   Not sure if that makes it more clear or not

Comment: Okay yeah that makes sense.. so it's basically a way to create "things" without them taking up any space, and then you can initialize them/allocate memory when and only when you need to use them to save resources. Is that right?

Comment: yes, you are actually creating a holder for "thing" without making the actual thing it holds.  It's generally useful for things with unknown / unbounded size.  if a map wasn't a reference type, every time you added an element that made it resize, it would get a new address (making all your variables point to the old map).   By having a reference type, i can refer to that and then growth operations just update the reference itself, my variable doesn't change.

Comment: Cool.. I think I'm starting to get it now. Thanks a lot =)

Answer (score 1):

First, to answer your question:

from https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#make

> The make built-in function allocates and initializes an object of type slice, map, or chan (only) [...]
>
> Map: An initial allocation is made according to the size but the
> resulting map has length 0. The size may be omitted, in which case
> a small starting size is allocated.

Secondly, there aren't goroutines in the code you posted.

Thirdly, make **initializes** the map and you probably shouldn't use it in every `HandleErr` call, because it would replace your current map. I think that what you want may be an initialization function like `NewErrorHandler` or `NewForm`. It is kind of make for your struct. For example:

```
func NewErrorHandler() ErrorHandler {
    return ErrorHandler{make(map[string]string)}
}
```

And finally why can't map initialize automatically? If it did you wouldn't have any control over initial size of your map. It may matter if you have mission critical code and you want it to be fast or low memory and know the size.

PS. There is also alternative way to initialize a map. If you want initialize an empty map you can write: `map[string]string{}`. If you want to create a map with initial values:

```
map[string]string{
    "a": "b",
    "c": "d",
}
```

So you could write you NewErrorHandler function like:

```
func NewErrorHandler() ErrorHandler {
    return ErrorHandler{map[string]string{}}
}
```

Comment: I think with my current method, using it in every HandleErr call is appropriate because only one error can occur at one time. For example, I try and send the email and Gmail refuses the credentials, so I call HandleErr and pass in my own error message. It would then return the view with the error so it wouldn't be able to catch any other error yet. But I think what you showed me will work well for when I have multiple errors that should all be "pushed" into the struct so all can be there in there together...correct?

Comment: If you can store only one error in the ErrorHandler then you shouldn't use a map. You can refactor your struct to sth like `type ErrorHandler struct { Key, Val string }` and have your init problem resolved. If you want to "push" errors I would recommend using slice instead of map.